# Does JavaScript from console affects real page or just my 'local copy'

Tags: javascript, console, http-post

there is some thing that troubles me.

There is some social-dating-site. The normal process is that page is showing you photos of some girls and you have to click Yes, if u like it, or No if you do not. If u both click Yes on each other photos- you get contact.

So now the point - i wrote javascript code that automatically click Yes if average photo rank is bigger than 8/10 :). I simulated click event on button, putted in loop for 300 times and run this from chrome console.

I know that click event is raised but, due to their politic, i cant click button Yes more than X times during one day, so i don't know now  if this click event really goes to server or just my 'local copy' or what ever is it called.

Does it work? I mean, can i have influence on the real outcome of server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The click will be (if you're firing the event the right way) the same as clicking on a button. There's no local copy stuff, what you do on the DOM on the console is real.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - i have just got results. So answer to my question is yes.